# Publish Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I created a random sheet and then clicked publish to publish this google sheet publicly but for some reason when i click on my [public link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2ZHdd0R-l1oSPbJK_fVGjVFc-64eYwsQVe2z3ek-v1HVzJ6QdrD7JpCK42bLRXihfsnMI1V0y1YUj/pub?output=csv) after signing out it will ask me to login again. This did not happen in the past. Has something changed with google sheet?

FYI i am not restricting access to anything or anyone i am publishing this as a public link but not able to access the link if i am not signed in.

I suggest others try it out and see if they get a different result or maybe there is restrictions on my account.

Comment: One can open a published sheet without logging in only when published as a web page. After all, how could one open a `.csv` or `.tsv` file on a browser. Having said that. I am not aware if this was even possible in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing issue that started yesterday. At my workplace, we are using it for years now. But suddenly the scripts started failing. HTML output is working fine but CSV, TSV formats are asking for login.

A temporary fix would be to change the sharing permission of the spreadsheet to Anyone on the Internet.

Issues started popping up on google support:
https://support.google.com/drive/thread/83705117?hl=en
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/83645178?hl=en
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/83744355?hl=en
https://support.google.com/drive/thread/83700244?hl=en

No solution or reply from the google team yet!!

Comment: In addition to this information and workaround this is the report of this behaviour: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863 . If you experience it you can star this report to indicate that you are also affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

not to sure, but when your posting, there should be a new option that lets you grant and restrict access. from the screen shot you provided, it should be somewhere in the "published content & settings" section at the bottom of the publish screen. once you do that it should open the access options and youll be able to allow anyone to view the document. The link you provided is still coming up as access denied. Let me know if you need more help and ill provide some pics and more details.

Comment: Yeah i have made sure there is no restrictions, in the published content

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that we experienced the same error yesterday - out of the blue our export scripts started failing.

We only experience this with CSV/TSV published Google Sheets, and we also made sure that there are no viewing restrictions whatsoever. If I publish as a website, I can still open that anonymously in a browser.

This is however useless as the data was being parsed as CSV.

A workaround is the following:

1. Click the Share button.
2. Click get link section of the modal.
3. Make sure "Anyone with the link" is selected.
4. Copy the URL and click done.
5. Post-fix URL with: /export?format=**csv**&gid=**0**
6. If you need a specific sheet, find the gid by clicking on that sheet in your browser and copying the gid from your browser's url. gid=0 is the first sheet.
7. Adjust all of your bash scripts with the new URL.

- Enjoy!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vXCw.png)